# How to convert a 2-d matrix to a cell array by rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays m and n:

```
n = {'1', '2'; '5', '6'},
 m ={'1', '2'; '3', '4'}.
```

I need to create a unique cell arrays `C = {'1', '2'; '3', '4'; '5', '6'}`. 
How can I do this efficiently ?

Comment: Do you guarantee that the elements of the cells are all single chars?

Comment: That small example isn't enough.  Can your elements in the cell array be **anything**, not just numbers converted to characters?

Comment: each element in the cell is a string

Comment: So you want to generate a cell array such that it contains all of the unique rows between `m` and `n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be self explanatory:

```
%% --- 'Transform this in a function, for fun and profit'

    %'Input data'
    n = {'1', '2'; '5', '6'};
    m = {'1', '2'; '3', '4'};

    %'Process data'
    a = [n;m];          %'All'
    u = cell(size(a));  %'Unique'

      ku    =   1;      %'Unique counter'
    u(ku,:) = a(1,:);   %'Add first row'

    %'Add only rows that do not exist in u'
    for ia = 2:size(a,1)
            found = false;   %'search flag'
            for iu = 1:ku
                    if all(strcmp(a(ia,:), u(iu,:)))
                            %'row is already registered'
                            found = true;
                            break;
                    end;
            end;
            if ~found
                    %'add row'
                    ku = ku+1;
                    u(ku,:) = a(ia,:);
            end;
    end;

    u = u(1:ku,:); %'Trim unused space in u'

    %'Sorting the unique rows in alpabetical order is left as exercise'
```

Answer (score 0):

Even thought @CST-Link answer is correct, I'd like to add my own, which uses a function that is quite powerful in matlab, `unique` :

```
n = {'1' '2'; '3' '4'};
m = {'1' '2'; '5' '6'};

C = num2cell(unique([cell2mat(n);cell2mat(m)],'rows'));
```

Note than on bigger input cells, @CST-Link's answer may probably be faster because of the double conversion I'm forced to use in order to use `unique` on rows